# In Typescript, I want to make a type guard for multiple arguments

Tags: typescript

I want to make a type guard for multiple arguments, but it seems be not possible.

With `isNull`, it is possible. But the more variables I need to check, the more uncomfortable it becomes.

Is there any way to solve the below situation?

```
const isNull = (v: any): v is null => {
  return v === null;
};

const hasSomeNull = (...args: any[]) => {
  return args.some(isNull);
};

const getNumber = (): number | null => {
  return Math.random() > .5 ? 12345 : null;
};

const getString = (): string | null => {
  return Math.random() > .5 ? 'abc' : null;
};

const v1 = getNumber();
const v2 = getNumber();
const v3 = getNumber();
const v4 = getNumber();
const v5 = getString();
const v6 = getString();
const v7 = getString();

// if (!( // This is too uncomfortable
//   isNull(v1) || isNull(v2) || isNull(v3) || isNull(v4) ||
//   isNull(v5) || isNull(v6) || isNull(v7)
// )) {
if (!hasSomeNull(v1, v2, v3, v4, v5, v6, v7)) {
  const r1: number = v1;
  const r2: number = v2;
  const r3: number = v3;
  const r4: number = v4;
  const r5: string = v5;
  const r6: string = v6;
  const r7: string = v7;
}
```

Comment: You could do something like [this](https://tsplay.dev/w62Gew) maybe? As you noted, type guard functions can only act on a single argument.  If that helps I can write up an answer

Comment: @jcalz Thank you!! but actually I want to use various typed values.
I'll change the content of question more clear.

Comment: Any reason you can't compose another type so you can pass a whole object of that type rather than 7 different parameters?

Comment: TypeScript GitHub issue for this: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/26916